# SELECT unique values and the associated timestamp without having the timestamp making things unique

Tags: mysql, select, join, distinct

I apologize for the poorly worded question.  It's best illustrated through an example and what I've come up with so far:

Table "myInfo" has columns:

```
1. id (PK) 
2. key 
3. value 
4. metaId
```

Table "meta" has columns:

```
1. id (PK) 
2. metaName 
3. metaValue 
4. instanceNum
```

metaId in the "myInfo" table correlates to a instanceNum in the "meta" table. The value of the "value" column changes sometimes over different rows with the metaId. Think of the metaId as a link to a timestamp value in the "meta" table("timestamp" and its value would go into the metaName and metaValue columns respectively).

I want to select the distinct values of the 'value' column in "myInfo". So far I have:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT mi.key, mi.value 
  FROM myInfo as mi JOIN metadata as meta 
 WHERE mi.metaId=meta.instanceNum 
   AND meta.key = 'timestamp' 
   AND mi.key='maxWeight';
```

But I ALSO want the timestamps associated with those values. So I want the output to look something like:

```
key       value   timestamp 
maxWeight 10 tons 15:00:05 2011-01-01 
maxWeight 5 tons  08:00:07 2011-10-12 
maxWeight 25 tons 13:05:09 2013-08-01
```

I can't place timestamp as one of the columns in my SELECT because then it will return duplicate mi.attrValue values too since the timestamp makes every row unique. I tried putting the DISTINCT keyword behind only mi.attrValue but I got a MySQL error.

Comment: FYI, the technical term for the link between two tables is _foreign key_.

Comment: how do you want to deduplicate the timestamps? By minute? By second? By day?

Comment: Where are the `attrName` and `attrValue` columns? What is `p` in your query? Shouldn't `as myInfo` be `as mi`?

Comment: Query doesn't match tables schemas, a tad confusing..

Comment: Sorry for the unmatching column names, I've fixed this.  My desired results show that the maxWeight CAN change(I only want the DIFFERENT values of maxWeight).  I can get rows with different weights, but I don't know how to get their associated timestamps.  I could probably do it via a subquery, but IDEALLY id like to see a more elegant query.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the desired output that you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested but grouping by a concat *might* work.

```
SELECT mi.key, mi.value, meta.value
  FROM myInfo as mi JOIN metadata as meta ON mi.metaId = meta.id
 WHERE mi.key = 'maxWeight'
   AND meta.key = 'timestamp' 
 GROUP BY CONCAT(mi.key, mi.value)
```

Although you'll still have the problem of which timestamp is shown. For example, if you have 3 records for a given key/value pair, which record will be shown in your result set?

```
key       value   timestamp 
maxWeight 10 tons 15:00:05 2011-01-01 
maxWeight 10 tons 08:00:07 2011-10-12 
maxWeight 10 tons 13:05:09 2013-08-01
```

The group by query will show just one of these results - but which? You'll need to think about ordering a group (which is a whole new ballgame)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mi.key, mi.value, min(meta.value) 
  FROM myInfo as mi JOIN metadata as meta 
 WHERE mi.metaId=meta.instanceNum 
   AND meta.key = 'timestamp' 
   AND mi.key='maxWeight' 
 group by mi.key,mi.value
```

Would get you what you want with the earliest timestamp value.